# CSS File not working on nested routes Express js

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express, ejs

I'm building a simple notes app to practice routing with express.

There are two endpoints: ***"/notes"*** and ***"/notes/add"***.

- The ***"/notes"*** endpoint renders a page that just lists all the notes created up until that point.
- The ***"/notes/add"*** endpoint is supposed to render a page where you are able to create a new note.

The problem is, I have a css stylesheet in a views directory with some generic styles. I want the styling in this stylesheet to apply to both of the pages rendered by the above mentioned endpoints.

However, it only applies to the ***"/notes"*** endpoint. On the ***"/notes/add"*** endpoint there is no styling applied, but I get the following error in the browser console (see attached image)...

[image]

Note that I already state in the index.js file that all static files should point to the "public" directory first when being referenced.

Any more experienced express users that can help a guy out? Thanks in advance.

/index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/notes/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('notes');
})

app.get('/notes/add/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('add');
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("LISTENING ON PORT 3000!");
})
```

/views/notes.ejs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <h1>All Notes</h1>
        <ul>
            <li class="list">Wish List</li>
            <li class="list">Homework for Friday</li>
            <li class="list">Workout Plan</li>
            <li class="list">Cooking Recipe</li>
            <li class="list">Monthly Budget Plan</li>
        </ul>
        <a href="/notes/add">Add +</a>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

/views/add.ejs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"/>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <textarea></textarea>
        </form>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

/public/style.css:

```
main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: red;
}

.list {
    font-size: 1.3rem;
}
```

Comment: use `href="/style.css"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add `/` in front of your **CSS LINK**

- The slash in front of the path means its calling from the root dir
- change your link to `href="/style.css"`it should work
  for more [detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71353431/cant-load-css-into-express-view-using-a-router)